# Can't redirect to '/api/auth/slack/callback' after Slack authentication

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-functions, slack

I'm implementing Slack webhook authentication with Firebase Cloud Function. However, the app is redirected to `/api/auth/slack/undefined` after choosing the channel I get notified. It should be redirected to `/api/auth/slack/callback`.

> Error: could not handle the request (/api/auth/slack/undefined)

Slack app setup done:
[image]
The Frontend code:

```
const slackAuthorizeURL= (uid) => 
  `https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_SLACK_CLIENT_ID}&scope='incoming-webhook'&redirect_uri=${process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUD_FUNCTIONS_ORIGIN}/api/auth/slack/callback&uid=${uid}&redirectTo=${window.location.href}`

<a href={slackAuthorizeURL('uid')}>Add to Slack</a>
```

The Server code:

```
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api')
app.get('/auth/slack/callback', (req, res) => {
  handleSlackUserInfo(req)
  res.redirect(req.session.redirectTo)
})

const handleSlackUserInfo = async (req) => {
  const { code, uid, redirectTo } = req.session
  const result = await new WebClient().oauth.v2.access({
    client_id: config.slack.client_id,
    client_secret: config.slack.client_secret,
    code,
  })
  console.log("result", result)
}
```

I added `uid=${uid}&redirectTo=${window.location.href}` after callback url. Is this wrong too?

Comment: Why are there quotes here `&scope='incoming-webhook'`?

Comment: I want to authenticate to Slack authentication with incoming-webhook scope.